# Load data in data-tables using AJAX in PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, filter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to load a `data` from `database` to data-table in view using `AJAX` in `Code-Igniter`.

I trying to **filter** data by selecting values from drop-down list box. If I directly load data by `CodeIgniter MVC`, it gives me proper result, but the value from selected `drop-down` will `reset`. So I'm trying to make `AJAX call` to filter data. But I'm not getting proper result.

**Here is my controller code:**

```
public function index()
    {   
        $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
        $data['username'] = $user->username;

        $data['user_id'] = $user->id;
        $user_id = $user->id;
        $data['groupId'] = $this->l->groupId($user_id);
        $data['group'] = $data['groupId']['0']->group_id;
        //$propId = $this->input->post('property_id');
        $propertyType=$this->input->post('property_type');
        $area=$this->input->post('area_id');
        $cluster=$this->input->post('cluster_id');
        $stageId=$this->input->post('property_status');

        if ($propertyType =='') {
            $propertyType=0;
        }
        if( $area ==''){
            $area =0;
        }
        if($cluster == ''){
            $cluster=0;
        }
        if ($stageId == '') {
            if($data['group']==1)
            {
              $stageId=0;
            } else {
              $stageId=4;
            }
        }
        $propDetail = $this->input->post('propDetail');

        $data['areas'] = $this->p->area();
        $data['clusters'] = $this->p->cluster();
        $data['property_stage'] = $this->p->selectPropertyStage();
        //$data['clusters'] = $this->p->clusterAll($area);
        $data['title'] = 'Property List';
        $data['property_type'] = $this->p->selectPropertyType();
        $data['properties'] = $this->p->getPropertyByAreaCluster($propertyType, $area, $cluster, $stageId);

        // echo "<pre>";
  //       print_r($data['properties']);
  //       echo "</pre>";
  //       exit();

        if ($data['properties']) {
        $html  = ''; 
          foreach($data['properties'] as $prop){
            $html .= '<td>'.$prop->property_code.'</td><br>';
          } 
        }
        echo $html;

        //$data['props'] = $this->p->PropView($propId);
        $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('Property/property_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
```

**Here is my model code:**

```
public function getPropertyByAreaCluster($propertyType, $area, $cluster, $stageId)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("call fetch_propertyType_Area_Cluster_Stage($propertyType,$area,$cluster,$stageId)");
        if ($query) {
            $data = $query->result();
            $query->next_result(); 
            $query->free_result();
            return $data;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Here is my AJAX code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example1').DataTable({
      "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, 200, -1], [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]],
      "order": [[ 6, "asc" ]]
    });
  });

  $('.propFilter').click(function(){
    url: <?php echo base_url('Property/index'); ?>,
    method:'POST',
    // data:{},
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (response) {
        $('#example1').show().html(response);
     },
  });
</script>
```

**Here is my view code:**

```
<form class="form-inline" action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Area:</label>
    <select class="form-control select2 country" name="area_id" id="areaId">
      <option value="0">All</option>
      <?php foreach ($areas as $area) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $area->area_id; ?>"><?php echo $area->area_name; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>                     
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Cluster:</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" name="cluster_id" id="cluster_id">
      <option value="0">All</option>
      <?php foreach ($clusters as $cluster){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cluster->cluster_id; ?>"><?php echo $cluster->cluster_name; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Property Type:</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" name="property_type">
      <option value="0">All</option>
      <?php if ($property_type) { foreach ($property_type as $type) {?>
        <option value="<?= $type->property_type_id; ?>"><?= $type->property_type_name;?></option>
      <?php }} ?>
    </select> 
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Stage:</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" name="property_status">
      <option value="0">All</option>   
      <?php foreach ($property_stage as $stage) { ?>  
        <option value="<?= $stage->stage_id; ?>"><?= $stage->stage_name; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>          
  <button type="submit" id="propFilter" name="propFilter" class="btn btn-primary propFilter">Filter</button>
  <div class="form-group">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
</form>
<table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <?php if( $properties ) {
      foreach ($properties as $property) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?= $property->property_code; ?></td> 
        </tr>
    <?php } } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```